# gitlab-runner: reusing artifacts after merge

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge

I'm setting up a new website. I am using jekyll and gitlab-runner for the build process.

There are two stages:

- build
- deploy

There are two git branches:

- master
- develop

I have currently a working setup such that I change files on the develop branch and push it to the remote repository, so I can develop on different local machines. After I made my changes and want to publish, I am merging the develop branch into master.

Everytime I am pushing to remote, the code will be automatically build by jekyll (build step). However only if I am pushing from master, additionally after the build step the artifact will be used for deployment in the deploy step.

Is it possible to reuse the already built artifact from the build process triggered by a push from develop branch after a merge to master? Otherwise everytime the build process for master is triggered but the resulting artifact would be the same as from the develop branch.

```
image: localhost:5000/website

cache:
  paths:
    - vendor/

before_script:
  - bundle install --path vendor

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - jekyll
  script:
    - bundle exec jekyll build -d public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - jekyll
  dependencies:
    - build
  script:
    - rsync -Pav ./public/. /websites/example.com/. --delete
  only:
    - master
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this, but why?  I guess if you are sure that your master branch is only ever updated by merges from develop it'd work.  You'd want to turn off the **build** stage for master, so it would always use the develop branch build artifacts.

Then there are ["well known URLs"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#downloading-the-latest-artifacts) for downloading gitlab-ci job artifacts.
You should be able to retrieve the latest artifacts from your develop branch with the following url

```
https://your-gitlab.com/your-gitlab-group/your-gitlab-project/-/jobs/artifacts/develop/download?job=build
```

I still don't think I'd recommend doing anything like this, but it is possible.

Comment: Why wouldn't you recommend this? What I want is that it should use the develop artifact automatically if it was a merge, if not the master build process should be triggered.